# Algebraic Closure terminology doubt

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

If F and K are fields, what does it mean when we say 'F is algebraically closed in K'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that $F$ is a subfield of $K$ and any element of $K$ algebraic over $F$ is in fact an element of $F$.

For instance, $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed in $\Bbb C (t)$. Less trivially, $\Bbb Q$ is algebraically closed in $\Bbb Q (t)$ and the algebraic numbers $\overline{ \Bbb Q}$ is algebraically closed in $\Bbb C$.